# Mui Stepper forces Grid to direction="column"

Tags: material-ui

I have a Mui Stepper in which I want to display some data by using a grid.
Usually you can tell the grid to do it in row fashion by direction="row".
BUT, when its in a stepper content, it will always display column. The very same code produces a different result when in a stepper.

[image: visualization]

If its some kind of parent style that overrides it, I cant find the right one. Thank you

Simple code example of mine:

```
<Stepper activeStep={0} orientation="vertical">
  <Step>
    <StepLabel>"Label"</StepLabel>
    <StepContent>
        <Grid container direction="row">
          <Grid item md={5} xs={8}><MyComponent /></Grid>
          <Grid item md={3.5} xs={8}><MyComponent /></Grid>
          <Grid item md={3.5} xs={8}><MyComponent /></Grid>
        </Grid>
    </StepContent>
  </Step>
</Stepper>
```

Edit: Stacks do work in both direction, although dont provide the feature do define the proportion its inhabitants, which I need. I noticed some other interactions that looked weird in stepper but not outside, most I could evade. Not this though.

Answer (score 0):

Problem has been solved. I didn't see, that the seem sets flex-basis to 96% for grid items in a stepper. Then, obviously, only 1 item fits in a row.